# Opening a file in a module regardless of current working directory

Tags: python, file, module

I have a module that deals with a database with the database inside the module directory, the file structure is as follows

```
app/
  foo.py
  database/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    database.db
```

Inside my `bar.py` file I have:

```
open("database.db")
```

When I import this database module it gives an error because the `database.db` file cannot be found, but it works when I use `open("database/database.db")`. Is there a way that I can open this file from any other directory and have the module access the file correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `__file__`. It keeps path to current python file. For example your `bar.py` file could contain something like this

```
from os import path
open(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "database.db"))
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! Worked like a charm!